# WordPress: How to add some of tags automatically during installation of WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes

How to add some of tags automatically during installation of WordPress theme?

Answer (score 0):

Put a `register_taxonomy()` in theme's `function.php`. I'm copy pasting [from](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) WP Codex

```
// Add new taxonomy, NOT hierarchical (like tags)
$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Writers', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Writer', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Writers' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Writers' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Writers' ),
    'parent_item'                => null,
    'parent_item_colon'          => null,
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Writer' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Writer' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Writer' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Writer Name' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate writers with commas' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove writers' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used writers' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'No writers found.' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Writers' ),
);

$args = array(
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_admin_column'     => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var'             => true,
    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'writer' ),
);

register_taxonomy( 'writer', 'book', $args );
```

This will not add tax on installation, but on first loading; anyway I think this should be the way (if you install it, you'll load it).

Comment: You're some way right. But is also true that a tag is just a taxonomy you can assign to a post_type. Your approach is better for general purpose tax (in this case a tag), but mine should also work for a more customized taxonomy tree. Isn't it?

Comment: Yeah definitely. I was just pointing out that he didn't seem to be asking that :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_insert_term` to add terms programmatically.  See the [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term).  There is also `wp_update_term`.  These functions work for all types of terms - categories and tags as well as custom taxonomies.

You will need to put these in a function in your functions.php file and then add it to the `init` action.

I haven't tested this code, but it should work:

```
function add_tags() {
    wp_insert_term(
        'Butts', // the tag/term name
        'tags',  // the taxonomy name
        array(
            'description' => 'Posts about Butts',
            'slug' => 'butts'
    ));
add_action( 'init', 'add_tags' );
```